# Incorrect syntax near the keyword if

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below SQL

```
DECLARE @ContractTerm int  
Declare @FIELDSSingle varchar(max)    
SET @ContractTerm = 2

SET @FIELDSSingle += '<td class="HeaderData"> Year ' +If(@ContractTerm = 2)Begin+' This is a sample '+ End + ' </td>'

select @FIELDSSingle
```

I am getting an error Incorrect syntax near the keyword if when I run it. What I want inside the string is logic to hide or show values based on conditions..Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca0ba/2906)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IF` is not an expression in SQL Server, you need to use `CASE`:

```
DECLARE @ContractTerm int  
Declare @FIELDSSingle varchar(max)    
SET @ContractTerm = 2

SET @FIELDSSingle += '<td class="HeaderData"> Year ' +
                      CASE WHEN @ContractTerm = 2 THEN ' This is a sample ' ELSE '' End  + 
                      ' </td>';

select @FIELDSSingle;
```

Comment: To be pedantic, IF is an expression, you just cannot use it like the OP did. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

Comment: @Leonidas199x to be pedantic IF is a statement, not an expression. An expression returns a single value where a statement is a collection of elements like expressions, identifiers and keywords that is used to control flow.

Comment: @SeanLange fair point, well made. Even got me with my own opening. Touché

Comment: @Leonidas199x Yeah, I was being pedantic with the use of *expression* in my answer. It didn't mean that `IF` doesn't exist in SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak You've lost me there old bean, the OP didn't refer to IF as being an expression? Anyway, doesn't really matter, I just wanted to point out that IF is valid in T-SQL and can be used, just not how the OP was using it, as you have explained.

Comment: @Leonidas199x op didn't refer to `IF` as an expression, but s/he was using it as such

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `CASE` expression which essentially is an `IF`

```
DECLARE @ContractTerm INT;
DECLARE @FIELDSSingle VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ContractTerm = 2;
SET @FIELDSSingle+='<td class="HeaderData"> Year '+CASE
                                                       WHEN @ContractTerm = 2
                                                       THEN ' This is a sample '
                                                       ELSE ''
                                                   END+' </td>';
SELECT
    @FIELDSSingle;
```

[Here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/04/sql-server-implementing-if-then-in-sql-server-with-case-statements/) is a pretty good read :)

Comment: `CASE` is not an statement in t-sql, it's an *expression*

Comment: @Lamak never really took that into consideration, amended it

Answer (score 0):

(Lamak's and dbajtr's answers are good, But for sake of variety I am writing this answer) You can break down lines as below :

```
DECLARE @ContractTerm int
DECLARE @Counter INT
Declare @FIELDSSingle varchar(max)
SET @Counter = 1
SET @ContractTerm = 2

SET @FIELDSSingle = '<td class="HeaderData"> Year ';
If(@ContractTerm = 2)
Begin
    set @FIELDSSingle +=' This is a sample ';
End 
set @FIELDSSingle +='</td>';

select @FIELDSSingle
```